# Adding each value in each cell from one column in plain Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

```
Name: SomeName
Transaction History
Date: 01/01/2000
Account stuff
Transaction Description         Type            Amount     Balance
1/21/16     Debit Card Purchase Distribution    -$11.48 $1,204.49
1/19/16     Debit Card Purchase Distribution    -$411.00    $1,215.97
1/19/16     Debit Card Purchase Distribution    -$67.18 $1,626.97
1/15/16     Debit Card Purchase Distribution    -$6.54      $1,694.15
1/7/16      Debit Card Purchase Distribution    -$48.75 $1,700.69
1/4/16      Contribution        Contribution    $1,000.00   $1,749.44
12/31/15    Interest            Interest        $0.06       $749.44
12/31/15    Contribution        Contribution    $130.43    $749.38
```

I have this csv data in a data.csv file. I would like to be able to add up the `Amount`. But add only the negative numbers, then add only the positive numbers.

I have tried the following.

```
CSV.foreach("data.csv", converters: :numeric, headers:true) do |row|
  puts "---------------------------------"
  p row[3]
 end
```

I get this in my console after doing `ruby csv_reader.rb

```
---------------------------------
nil
---------------------------------
nil
---------------------------------
nil
---------------------------------
"Amount"
---------------------------------
"-$11.48"
---------------------------------
"-$411.00"
---------------------------------
"-$67.18"
---------------------------------
"-$6.54"
---------------------------------
"-$48.75"
---------------------------------
"$1,000.00"
---------------------------------
"$0.06"
---------------------------------
"$130.43"
```

They're strings. even after calling `converters: :numeric`, I also don't see the headers for each one of the cells, which i thought would be turned into this.

```
---------------------------------
Amount: "$1,000.00"
---------------------------------
Amount: "$0.06"
---------------------------------
Amount: "$130.43"
```

maybe I'm going over my head with this, and confusing things.

the following gives me `undefined method 'start_with?'` and `undefined method 'gsub!'`

```
CSV.foreach("Downloads/data.csv", converters: :numeric, headers:true) do |row|
  puts "---------------------------------"

  minus = Array.new

    # minus << row[3] if row[3].gsub!("/^-\$/")
    minus << row[3] if row[3].start_with?("/^-\$/")
  puts minus.inspect
end
```

What am i missing? Would love some good material on this. Thanks

UPDATE:

```
require 'csv'
require 'pry'

# Initiate a empty array to store amount data
amount_column_data = []

# read from file - Get only the amount column
CSV.foreach("Downloads/data.csv") {|row| amount_column_data << row[3]}

# remove the first 5 lines which is an array
#   * name, description, and some text
only_numbers_data = amount_column_data.drop(5)

#initiating new empty array to store new data without the $ sign
no_dollar_sign = []

# remove the $ sign from the numbers
only_numbers_data.map {|cell| no_dollar_sign << cell.gsub!(/\$/, "")}

# Select only the negative numbers, add the numbers together and round them up up e.g. -300.00
p no_dollar_sign.select {|f| f.to_f < 0 }.inject {|result, value| result.to_f + value.to_f }.round(6)
```

This is my final solution.

Comment: First 3 items are `nil`, that's why `undefined method 'start_with?'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'csv'
require 'pry'

# Initiate a empty array to store amount data
amount_column_data = []

# read from file - Get only the amount column
CSV.foreach("Downloads/data.csv") {|row| amount_column_data << row[3]}

# remove the first 5 lines which is an array
#   * name, description, and some text
only_numbers_data = amount_column_data.drop(5)

#initiating new empty array to store new data without the $ sign
no_dollar_sign = []

# remove the $ sign from the numbers
only_numbers_data.map {|cell| no_dollar_sign << cell.gsub!(/\$/, "")}

# Select only the negative numbers, add the numbers together and round them   up up e.g. -300.00
p no_dollar_sign.select {|f| f.to_f < 0 }.inject {|result, value|     result.to_f + value.to_f }.round(6)
```

I'm going to add my answer here, since it accomplished what i needed. There might be a better way of doing this though. Open for suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First 3 items are `nil`, that's why `undefined method 'start_with?'`.

Best way would be, save all `row[0]` in a array. Then manipulate that array.

Like:

```
amounts = []

CSV.foreach("Downloads/data.csv", converters: :numeric, headers:true) do |row|
  amounts << row[3]
end

amounts = amounts.map(&:to_i) #Array of only integers.
#amounts = amounts.map(&:to_i).reject{|n| n == 0} #Exclude the ZEROs if you want.

minus = amounts..select{|n| n < 0}
sum_of_minus = minus.inject(0, &:+)
```

Comment: Here i get 0 as my return value. I'm going to try tweaking this and see if I can get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The data file you have is not a CSV file - it's a space separate file, one issue parsing it is that even the data lines has values with spaces (e.g. `Debit Card Purchase`) - hence, it is very difficult to parse it in structured manner using `:col_sep => ' '`.

For your specific case, if you are interested in amount values from the lines which have `$...` values, then, you could do something like below.

```
require "csv"

amounts = []
CSV.foreach("/path/to/file.csv", :col_sep => ' ') do |row|
    amounts << row[-2].gsub(/\$/,'').to_f if row[-2] =~ /\$/
end

p amounts
#=> [-11.48, -411.0, -67.18, -6.54, -48.75, 1.0, 0.06, 130.43]
```

I will let you add the part to add the positive and negative values as your question is bit unclear in that aspect.

Comment: Unfortunately this method gives me an error saying `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unclosed quoted field on line 1.`

Comment: I took the contents of data you shared in your question, and saved in a `file.csv`, and above code works on that.  I run this code on windows - unless you have different file or your OS is different that windows and that is causing some issues - it should work just fine.